# Is it fine to use jQuery with Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, frameworks, libraries

I'm wondering if it is fine to include and use jQuery in an Angular project. Should I prefer Vanilla JS when I write my functions or can I use jQuery selectors and methods?

Comment: Read [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Thanks Satpal. Good documentation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using data on your page, it's recommended don't use jquery to manipulate bound data at all! But for elements which are not bound to angular, you can use jquery.

My personal experience about angular is using angular alone but with a right and strong architecture which allow you handle every place of your code. Otherwise with combining Jquery and Angular, may be, you face with some conflicts in future.